# Python: Cutting column from list and storing as list

Tags: python

PyNoob checking in, attempting to get more reps with python and stop using so much bash.  I have a csv file that contains many lines of 'devicename;port;portchannel' and I have read this into what I assume is a list that looks like below.

```
['deviceA;portZ;portchanC', 'device1;port3;portchan1', 'deviceA;port3;portchan1',  'deviceD;portR;portchanE', 'device2;portG;portchan1', 'deviceB;portZ;portchan1', 'deviceE;portX;portchan2']
```

Now what I want to do, is strip(cut?) the first element (delimited by ';') from each string in the list and store it to a new list.  I would also like to unique it.  I have attempted many different code samples I have found on here from like questions but have yet to find something that works.

desired output would be

```
a = ['deviceA', 'device1', 'deviceD', 'device2', 'deviceB', 'deviceE']
```

Appreciate the help!

Comment: You can look at [csvreader](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/csv.html) to ease working with csv files.

Comment: @Marcin, the asker is requesting how to iterate, split, and group stuff from a CSV file. They've already figured out the CSV part :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list = ['deviceA;portZ,portchanC', ... , 'deviceE;portX,portchan2']    
output = [ele.split(';')[0] for ele in list]
uniques = set(output)
```

This should give you what you want. Keep reading if you want to understand what's going on.

`somestring.split('delimiter')` will return an array of the string, and [0] will grab the first element. So `'deviceA;portZ,portchanC'.split(';')` will return `['deviceA','portZ' ,'portchanC']` . so `'deviceA;portZ;portchanC'.split(';')` will give you `'deviceA'`.

The `for ele in list` will iterate over every item in your list, and assign it to a variable named `ele`. So what this code does is iterate over the list, split each item by ';', return the first part, and put it all together in a list. The last line will give you a unique set from that list.

---

An alternative, more "beginner" way this could also be done is as follows, it's similar to what you may see in other languages. Both methods are valid. In the below one, we create an empty list, `a`. Then we loop over your list, split it, store the results in `device`, then take the first element of that list (which will be the string before the `;` and append/push/add it to `a`:

```
my_list = ['deviceA;portZ,portchanC', ... , 'deviceE;portX,portchan2']    
a = []

for ele in my_list:
    arr = ele.split(';')
    device = arr[0]
    a.append(device)
a = set(a)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation, this worked (the first example) and I even know why it works :D

Answer (score 1):

```
list(set([l.split[';'][0] for l in a]))
```

or

```
list(set(map(lambda l: l.split[';'][0], a)))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv

with open('path/to/file') as infile:
    answer = []
    for row in csv.reader(infile, delimiter=';'):
        answer.append(row[0])
```

That will get you all the device names without `uniq`ing. The following will `uniq` them, but you might lose the order in which they appear in your file:

```
import csv

with open('path/to/file') as infile:
    answer = set()
    for row in csv.reader(infile, delimiter=';'):
        answer.add(row[0])
```

If you want to maintain the original order, you're going to have to do some heavy lifting:

```
import csv

with open('path/to/file') as infile:
    answer = []
    seen = set()
    for row in csv.reader(infile, delimiter=';'):
        dev = row[0]
        if dev not in seen:
            seen.add(dev)
            answer.append(dev)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, this also works and I appreciate the detailed explanation!